# Jpeg Image : zlib.error : Error -3 while decompressing data : incorrect header check

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pickle, zlib

I have a jpg image that is in memory and therefore is in bytes. I then compress it with the following:

```
zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(self.fileInstance))
```

I compress it to store it into a MongoDB database. This image is one of the elements in the record that I save. I save the with the following.

```
list_search_result = list(search_result)
json_search_result = json.dumps(list_search_result, cls=Encoder, indent=2)
```

I got an error with bytes and Json, so I simply convert the bytes image to a string with the following.

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import json 
import datetime
class Encoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
            return str(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return str(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj,bytes):
            return str(obj)
        return super(Encoder, self).default(obj)
```

Now, I want to recover the image from the json file. I thought that doing the same steps in the opposite order would work but no.

So here is what I do to store:

```
image -> pickle -> compress -> str -> json
```

I thought this would work:

```
json -> bytes -> decompress -> depickle -> image
```

I receive the `zlib.error : Error -3` during the following:

```
  image = pickle.load(zlib.decompress(attachment[1].encode()))

  image = io.BytesIO(image)
  dt = Image.open(image)
```

**EDIT:**

Okay so I was toying around, and I think the issue might be the `.encode()`. I start with `b" "`. After `str(b" ")`, I get `"b' '"`. If I do the `.encode()`, I get `b"b' '"`. How do I deal with this?

Comment: don't use `str()` - it is wrong idea - use `.decode()`. OR write it in databes as bytes. You may also keep  file as string using `base64`

Comment: if you have bytes `b""` then you don't have to convert it to string and later back to bytes.

Comment: many web APIs send images in JSON as `base64`

Comment: I don't understand why you use pickle - it is waste of time. You could compress direcly image. `pickle` may only add extra bytes so you will have only bigger file. And other think: most images already use some kind of compressions and using zip may not create smaller file. The only useful think can be `base64` if database doesn't have special field to keep bytes (`blob` field in some SQL databases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str()` is useful to display something - it creates text readable for human.

It may show that you had bytes (`"b''"`) or it may show string like `\xe0` for values which can't be converted to chars. But it doesn't have to create text useful for keeping in database.

Many databases have field to keep bytes and then you could keep image as bytes (without converting to pickle which may only add more bytes, and without compressing because images already use some compression)

If you have to keep (or send by internet) file as string then better convert it to `base64`. And this method used by some `APIs` to send image in `JSON`.

---

Convert image to base64

```
import base64

fh = open('lenna.png', 'rb')
data = fh.read()
fh.close()

data = base64.b64encode(data).decode()

print(text[:100])  # text

# ... save in database ...
```

Convert base64 to image

```
# ... read from database ...

data = base64.b64decode(text.encode())

print(data[:100])  # bytes

fh = open('lenna.png', 'wb')
fh.write(data)
fh.close()
```

Result:

```
# text

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAIAAAB7GkOtAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4nOzbXa5tS5Il5DHMzH3OtfY+

# bytes 

b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00{\x1aC\xad\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00 \x00IDATx\x9c\xec\xdb]\xaemK\x92%\xe41\xcc\xcc}\xce\xb5\xf6>\xe7\xde\x88\xc8\xa2\x1e\xea\x85\x16 !$\x10\x88?\x05/t\x06\x95\xc8\xe2\x95\x06\xd0'
```

Tested on image `lenna.png` (Wikipedia: [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna))

[image]

Comment: > str() is useful to display something - it creates text readable for human. -- this isn't exactly correct -- what you're describing is `repr`.  in this case `str` is falling back to `__repr__` for bytes

Comment: @AnthonySottile you are right - I shortened this explanation because it wasn't important for me in my solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly! You are right. pickling is completely unnecessary. Thanks for catching that. I also did away with compression. Worked very well. Thanks again.